# Excel AVERAGEIF with TODAY() function as criteria

Tags: excel, date, conditional-statements

I have values in column c that i want averaged if they occurred in the last seven days (corresponding dates in column a). i can't get the averageif function to work properly, as I need each individual piece of data to be evaluated separately if it falls within the last seven days. this seems like a function that would be used all the time, but i googled for 45 minutes and couldn't find anything.

Comment: I need to find the average of the data in column C for the last seven days (I have data from months past). The date is indicated for each of the entries in the spreadsheet in column A. It needs to be some type of AVERAGEIF function, I believe.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have Excel 2007 to test, but I'll give it a shot:

```
 = AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$100, ">=" & (TODAY()-6), $C$2:$C$100)
```

I assume the "last 7 days" means compared to TODAY(), not compared to some other row of data?

Use NOW() instead of TODAY() and "-7" instead of "-6" if you want time sensitivity, not just looking at today and anything back up to 6 days ago (i.e., a total of 7 days).

If *each row* of data should have an average of the past 7 days *compared to itself* rather than compared to today (i.e., you want a different rolling average in each row), use something like:

```
 = AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$100, ">=" & ($A2-7), $C$2:$C$100)
```

in row 2 and paste down, the $A2 will adjust to use the reference point of the current row's date/time. If the dates are sorted already, you can optimize the formula by using $A2 and $C2 instead of $A$100 and $C$100 (pasting down will increase the range for each additional row).

Comment: The second function does not work as it will average every value that is greater than 7 days from the current row's date.  Which includes the past 7 days and every day in the dataset after it.

Comment: Good catch, @jcmcbeth. Since `AVERAGEIF` doesn't have a "between" operator, I think a solution would require an array formula rather than `AVERAGEIF`.